# How Do I Hide and Unhide Columns Using Checkboxes and Script in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Trying to create a script that will do the following:

- Only operate for one specific worksheet within my workbook
- Hide multiple non-sequential columns when a checkbox is checked
- Unhide multiple non-sequential columns when a checkbox is unchecked
- Incorporate three checkboxes total for three separate column groups

Here is what I'd like to set up:

- When the checkbox within cell A25 is checked on worksheet 'Product Pricing', columns C,E,I,K,O,Q,U,W,AA,AC,AG,AI,AM,AO,AS,AU,AY,BA,BE,BG,BK,BM will hide.
- When the checkbox within cell A25 is unchecked on the same worksheet, the same columns will unhide.
- Then I need to repeat the above functions with two additional column sets.

I'm not a programmer by trade but can create some pretty robust spreadsheets using scripts, functions and conditional formatting. I appreciate anyone willing to help me learn something new that I can apply to this project as well as future projects.

Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be something like this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const name = e.source.getActiveSheet().getName();
  if (name != 'Sheet1') return; // if not Sheet1 do nothing
  const col = e.range.columnStart;
  if (col != 1) return; // if not column A do nothing
  const row = e.range.rowStart;
  switch (row) {
    case 1: var ranges = ['d','e']; break; // checkbox on row 1
    case 2: var ranges = ['f','g']; break; // checkbox on row 2
    case 3: var ranges = ['h','i']; break; // checkbox on row 3
    default: return;
  }
  const value = e.value;
  if (value == 'TRUE') hide_cols(ranges); // if check   --> hide
  else unhide_cols(ranges);               // if uncheck --> unhide
}  

function hide_cols(ranges) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  ranges.forEach(r => sheet.hideColumn(sheet.getRange(r+'1')));
}

function unhide_cols(ranges) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  ranges.forEach(r => sheet.unhideColumn(sheet.getRange(r+'1')));
}
```

[image]

[Here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kq5buRPcjwHqQHIJkwme72Ueh8OVy4bVNlKrgGlh9Go/edit?usp=sharing) is my sheet.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName() == "Sheet0" && e.range.columnStart == 1 && e.range.rowStart == 25 && e.value == "TRUE") {
    [1,5,9,11,17,21,23,27,29].forEach(c => sh.hideColumns(c));
  }
  if(sh.getName() == "Sheet0" && e.range.columnStart == 1 && e.range.rowStart == 25 && e.value == "FALSE") {
    [1,5,9,11,17,21,23,27,29].forEach(c => sh.showColumns(c));
  }
}
```

You will need to add the rest of the column numbers I got tired of adding them.

Also this may take longer than 30 seconds so you may require an installable onEdit trigger